# Rotation locking in Xcode doesn't work with React Native on an iPad

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to limit my app to only landscape rotation, so I do the following in XCode (8.1):

[image]

That seems to work when running on an iPhone simulator (tested 6 and 7), but not on an iPad simulator (tested Pro and Retina). I also tested on a physical iPad Air 2 and it rotates as well.

Is there any way I can get it to work on an iPad without having to use something like react-native-orientation? I'm using React Native 0.34.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug in Xcode, but it doesn't seem to work on an iPad if "Devices" is set to Universal. I changed it to iPad then it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I'm deploying an app to iPhone and iPad and I have the same problem, need to lock to only portrait orientation but it doesn't work, it still rotating. I can't change universal option because I need the app for both devices iPad and iPhone. And anyway change Universal to iPhone or iPad doesn't make it work neither. Do you know something about this?

Comment: Sorry, this was nearly 2 years ago and I haven't looked at it since. The answer I gave worked for me, so I'm not sure what else you'd need to do at this point, since XCode and React Native have changed a lot since then.